# Find all entire functions in the complex plane such that $|f(z)| \leq 2 |z|^{3/2} - 1$ for $|z| \geq 2$ and $f(0)=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find all entire functions in the complex plane such that $|f(z)| \leq 2 |z|^{3/2} - 1$ for $|z| \geq 2$ and $f(0)=1$.

I know how to do this when $a$ in $|z|^a$ is an integer. For that case, we can use Liouville's Theorem. Is this case similar and how do we proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can argue that if the analytic function is bounded by $2|z|^{(3/2)}$ then for sufficieny large $|z|$ it's bounded by $c|z|^2$ for any positive constant $c$.  An entire function having such a bound must either be nonsingular or have only a first-order pole at infinity; thus it must have the form $f(z)=1+bz$.  Add in the absolute value requirement at the circle $|z|=2$ where $|f|\leq(2(2^{3/2})-1)$ and you can place bounds on $b$.

Comment: All too easy ;-))  +1

Comment: Mot Not everyone agrees, apparently, I got a downvote!  o_O